# SlickSlider (slick.js) with fixed height on mobile

Tags: jquery, css, slick.js

I would like to set fixed height of SlickSlider because it gets really small on mobile devices. I am able to do this with this piece of code:

```
$("#carousel").find(".slick-slide").height("300px").css({'object-fit': 'cover'});
```

It's OK for most devices instead of Windows mobiles and older Android devices (object-fit property is supported by Android Browser 4.4.4+).

Is there any chance to do this (maybe without object-fit property)? I need to use same images which can be cropped.

Comment: There's an [object-fit polyfill](https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit) if you're interested in replicating the effect in unsupported browsers.